# Module parse failed on node file from steamworks.js npm package

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the steamworks.js npm package within my Ionic Angular project.

The project fails to compile due to the 'Module parse failed' error. There are four node files that trigger this error.

[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Z74.png)
[One of the node files that is triggering this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6sVd.png)

I am not sure how to handle an error like this as i've never had one before.